# Comparing each sequences of two list of sequences by pairwiseAlignment in r

Tags: r, list, sequence, mapply

I'm trying to obtain the `PairwiseAlignments` score from the comparison between each elements sequences of two multiple list of sequences by the  function `pairwiseAlignmen(from Biostrings)` with `mapply`. Could that be possible?

This is the code that I'm trying:

```
if (!requireNamespace("BiocManager", quietly = TRUE))
  install.packages("BiocManager")

BiocManager::install("Biostrings")
library(Biostrings)
s1 <- DNAString("ACTTCACCAG")
s2 <-DNAString("ACTTCACCCC")
S<-c(s1,s2)

R1 <- DNAString("ACTTCACCAT")
R2 <-DNAString("ACTTCACCCC")
R<-c(R1,R2)

Result<-mapply(FUN = function(S, R) {
  pairwiseAlignment(S, R,
                    substitutionMatrix = nucleotideSubstitutionMatrix(1, 0, TRUE),
                    gapOpening = 0, gapExtension = 0)
}, S, R)

The message that apeared in the the console is:

Error in dots[[1L]][[1L]] : this S4 class is not subsettable
```

I would like to have a list or vector for calculate the mean of the score:

```
S1 vs R1
Global PairwiseAlignmentsSingleSubject (1 of 1)
pattern: ACTTCACCAG
subject: ACTTCACCAT
score: 9 

S1 vs R2
Global PairwiseAlignmentsSingleSubject (1 of 1)
pattern: ACTTCACCAG
subject: ACTTCACCCC
score: 8 


 S2 vs R1

Global PairwiseAlignmentsSingleSubject (1 of 1)
pattern: ACTTCACCCC
subject: ACTTCACCAT
score: 8 

S2 vs R2

Global PairwiseAlignmentsSingleSubject (1 of 1)
pattern: ACTTCACCCC
subject: ACTTCACCCC
score: 10 




final score

Result$score

9, 8, 8, 10
```

Comment: Please include all `library` lines as these methods are not part of base R. And please explain the issue with current code? Any error or undesired results?

Comment: It seems that all you need is to replace `c` with `list`  in `S<-c(s1,s2)` and `R<-c(R1,R2)`. Voting to close.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, and I´m sorry for the details that I dídn´t write. I change the c by list and  the code work, but just obtain the comparation between S1 and R1 and S2 and R2, and I´ll need all the possible comparation.Any idea? Thanks